# C++: memory leak in tbb

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, tbb

Valgrind has reported a memory leak on an application I'm working with, inside tbb:

```
==00:00:00:42.164 12570== 126 bytes in 7 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 5,026 of 6,496
==00:00:00:42.164 12570==    at 0x4C29BC3: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==00:00:00:42.164 12570==    by 0x9387AF9: strdup (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==00:00:00:42.164 12570==    by 0x1E47A8A2: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libtbb.so.2)
==00:00:00:42.164 12570==    by 0x1E4833AC: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libtbb.so.2)
==00:00:00:42.164 12570==    by 0x1E481653: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libtbb.so.2)
==00:00:00:42.164 12570==    by 0x1E481878: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libtbb.so.2)
==00:00:00:42.164 12570==    by 0x5F7CEA4: start_thread (in /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.17.so)
==00:00:00:42.164 12570==    by 0x93F98DC: clone (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
```

gdb was able to find a more detailed backtrace for the strdup:

```
(gdb)
#0  0x00007ffff35d4ae0 in strdup () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007fffe05bf8a3 in __itt_thread_set_name_init_3_0(char const*) () from /lib64/libtbb.so.2
#2  0x00007fffe05c83ad in tbb::internal::market::create_one_job() () from /lib64/libtbb.so.2
#3  0x00007fffe05c6654 in tbb::internal::rml::private_worker::run() () from /lib64/libtbb.so.2
#4  0x00007fffe05c6879 in tbb::internal::rml::private_worker::thread_routine(void*) () from /lib64/libtbb.so.2
#5  0x00007ffff6a87ea5 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#6  0x00007ffff36468dd in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
(gdb) p $rdi
$1 = 140736957592936
(gdb) p (char *)(140736957592936)
$2 = 0x7fffe05d3568 "TBB Worker Thread"
```

Given this, the leaked memory is actually a string, used to name the thread, equal to "TBB Worker Thread", see here:
https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneTBB/blob/master/src/tbb/market.cpp#L599

The strdup, invoked here:
https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneTBB/blob/master/src/tbb/tools_api/ittnotify_config.h#L476

appears to never be released. I went through the tbb source but did not see anywhere that it would be free'd.

I've extracted the tbb logic from that application into a stand-alone program, which reproduces the leak in terms of a clear linear rate of memory increase (although for some reason does not show up on valgrind):

```
#include <tbb/parallel_for.h>
#include <thread>
#include <cstdio>

// compile with g++ tbb.cpp -std=c++11 /lib64/libtbb.so.2 -lpthread -o tbb

struct ApplyFoo {

    void operator()( const tbb::blocked_range<int>& r ) const {
        return;
    }
};

void myfunc() {
    tbb::parallel_for(tbb::blocked_range<int>(0, 12000, 10000), ApplyFoo());
}

void functhread() {

    std::thread *threads[10];

    while (1) {
        for (int i=0;i<100000;i++) {
            for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {
                threads[i] = new std::thread(myfunc);
            }
    
            for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {
                threads[i]->join();
                delete threads[i];
            }       
        }
        printf("Sleeping now...\n");
        sleep(30);
    }
}

int main() {

    std::thread t1(functhread);
    std::thread t2(functhread);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

It seems that the threads calling tbb::parallel_for have to themselves die for the leak to happen. There is probably some thread-local storage for tbb, stored in the thread that calls parallel_for, that is not being cleaned up. That's why a hierarchy of threads like seen above is required to reproduce this. However, I could not find any documentation in tbb that states that any extra cleanup is required, or that this paradigm is illegal with tbb.

The 30 seconds sleep is strictly unnecessary, but its a "grace time" to give tbb a chance to clean stuff up, to prove that its not simply an issue of the program overloading itself. During this grace period, we can see the number of threads falls to 3 (main thread + two std::threads), meaning all tbb threads have exited, yet the memory use over time persists and increases very clearly.

I've searched for tbb leaks on stackoverflow but none of those posts describe a situation applicable to this one.

```
root@localhost:~ [22:00:55] $ ps -o rss -p $(pidof tbb)
  RSS
37352
root@localhost:~ [22:00:55] $ ps -o rss -p $(pidof tbb)
  RSS
61552
root@localhost:~ [22:04:31] $ ps -o rss -p $(pidof tbb)
  RSS
61960
root@localhost:~ [22:04:32] $ ps -o rss -p $(pidof tbb)
  RSS
62156
root@localhost:~ [22:04:33] $ ps -o rss -p $(pidof tbb)
  RSS
62392
root@localhost:~ [22:14:36] $ ps -o rss -p $(pidof tbb)
  RSS
131340
root@localhost:~ [22:15:00] $ ps -o rss -p $(pidof tbb)
  RSS
133508
root@localhost:~ [22:19:47] $ ps -o rss -p $(pidof tbb)
  RSS
167192
root@localhost:~ [22:19:48] $ ps -o rss -p $(pidof tbb)
  RSS
207644
```

Edit: clarifying the question here: is this a bug in tbb, or is the library being misused by the application (e.g. missing some cleanup steps, etc)?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Is this a bug in the library or is the library being misused by the application (e.g. missing some cleanup calls, etc)?

Comment: *I went through the tbb source but did not see anywhere that it would be free'd.* -- Maybe you should be informing the tbb engineers about your findings if you really believe that there is no call to `free` for the corresponding `strdup`.  All anyone else can tell you is yes, `strdup` without a `free` is a memory leak, regardless of the application.

Comment: _Maybe you should be informing the tbb engineers about your findings_ -- We sometimes check SO. I was able to reproduce your example. However, the source of memory leak is not clear. It is not `__itt_thread_set_name_init_3_0` because it is not called without the itt collector (valgrind also does not report it, maybe it was an issue in the previous versions). I will continue the investigation and let you know when the issue is clear.

Comment: I could not find any memory leaks with the latest TBB. I tried several systems and RSS is stable. The only one system showed slight RSS increasing over  time but it seems as memory fragmentation in the allocator (the number of allocations is not growing but allocator continues calling map).

Comment: Can you show where the strdup referenced in the original post is freed? Perhaps it wasn't present in the version the application I'm working with is linked to (which happens to be 4.1.9)